# Is there a rigorous definition of an "instance" of a constructor function?

Tags: javascript

```
function Foo() {}

var f1 = new Foo(); // This is clearly an instance of Foo.

var f2 = Object.create(Foo.prototype); // Is this an instance of Foo?
```

Clearly `f2 instanceof Foo` returns `true`, but I am talking in the more general object oriented sense.

Finally, what is the difference between `f1` and `f2` such that Chrome can distinguish between them when printing them to the console?

```
console.log(f1); //  Foo {}
console.log(f2); //  Object {}
```

Comment: There is no difference from the JS view point. It's just some internal labeling that Chrome does for pretty-printing in the console.

Comment: Do you know where this labelling resides. Is it in the spec?

Comment: It's not in the spec, that's why I said "internal" and "no JS difference" :-) It's probably somewhere in the V8 source of [[construct]].

Comment: OK, make this an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a rigorous definition of an “instance” of a constructor function?

No. You could use the definition of `instanceof`, that is an object needs to inherit from the respective prototype object. But in the OOP sense, it usually is also implied that the object was constructed by a call to the constructor; or at least somehow implements the interface (same properties) as it would be set up in the constructor.

> Finally, what is the difference between `f1` and `f2` such that Chrome can distinguish between them when printing them to the console?

That's something internal to Chrome, only for pretty-printing in the console (well, and maybe V8 does some other optimisations based on such a label).

The two objects are indistinguishable from the JavaScript viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

```
var f1 = new Foo(); // This is clearly an instance of Foo.

var f2 = Object.create(Foo.prototype); // Is this an instance of Foo?
```

currently both are `Foo` instances only.

`Object.create()` creates the instance of passed argument.if nothing is passed it will create the instance of object.